# What does an illustrated undirected graph with only 1 endpoint look like?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, graph-theory, spanning-tree

How do you illustrate an undirected graph 4 nodes/vertexes, but have them all connected?  If you divide the nodes (at any of the nodes of the graph) into two subsets, how would that work or look like?

I tried drawing the undirected graph in C formations, but if the the graph at one of the nodes was divided, another node would end up completely disconnected.

Comment: What do you mean by "endpoint"?

Answer (score 0):

4 node undirected graph with all nodes connected by one hop

[image]

Divided into two subsets

[image]